# Iterate through Linq to Entities results until condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here is the scenario, I have a query that returns events in a dat. Starting with shift start (SS) I need to find a shift end (SE) if I find it, move on to the next, if not, generate an error and record the row it happened on.

```
List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
List<int> errorListRow = new List<int>();
var itCompareDay = (from h in db.DailyGPSTables
                    where h.EmplID == EmpID
                       && (h.EventDateTime >= startDate
                       && h.EventDateTime <= endDate)
                       && (h.EventType == "SS" || h.EventType == "JS" || h.EventType == "LS" || h.EventType == "LE" || h.EventType == "JE" || h.EventType == "SE")
                    orderby h.EventDateTime
                    select h).ToList();
int rowNumber = -1;
foreach (DailyGPSTable e in itCompareDay)
{
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;
   string EOOmessage="";
   string eventText="";
   int dayCountSs = itCompareDay.Count(k => k.EventType == "SS" && (k.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() == e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()));
   int dayCountSe = itCompareDay.Count(k => k.EventType == "SE" && (k.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() == e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()));
   int dayCountJS = itCompareDay.Count(k => k.EventType == "JS" && (k.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() == e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()));
   // Response.Write("<br> Count of event type is ss on " + e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() + " is  " + itCompareDay.Count(k => k.EventType == "SS" && k.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() == e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()));
   if (dayCountSs != dayCountSe)
   {
      eventText = "";
      if (dayCountSs > dayCountSe)
      {
         eventText = "Shift End (SE)";
      }
      else
      {
         eventText = "Shift Start (SS)";
      }
      EOOmessage = " On " + e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() + " there is a missing " + eventText;
      errorList.Add(EOOmessage);
      errorListRow.Add(rowNumber);   
  }
```

The above code returns an error for the entire day, I was heading down this path to find the line where a shift start had no ending tag and highlight that row. The day can have multiple shifts but have to have an ending tag.

```
if (dayCountSs != dayCountSe)
{
   eventText = "";
   if (dayCountSs > dayCountSe)
   {
      string dayEvents = e.EventType;
      Response.Write("SS greater than SE >Event Type " + dayEvents +"<BR>");
      for (int i = 0; i < dayCountSs; i++)
      {
         Response.Write("Should see a count here " + i);
         if (dayEvents[i].ToString() != "SS")
         {
            i = i + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            errorListRow.Add(rowNumber);
            eventText = "Shift End (SE)";
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      eventText = "Shift Start (SS)";
   }
   EOOmessage = " On " + e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() + " there is a missing " + eventText;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a simple data example with which the error occurs? Your code readability is... lacking, which is hindering my understanding of the logical succession of operations you expect to have. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be allround helpful here.

Comment: @Hogan My question would be how do I iterate through the days events to find an unpaired SE tag. For example on 11/8/2018 I have 3 shifts and for that day I have 3 instances of the SS tag but only 2 SE tags which means the 3rd shift started but never ended.  How do I find the 3rd SS tag to add an error condition to my list and record the row number?

Comment: That is the problem you are trying to solve.  We don't just write solutions for people here -- we help with questions.  In trying to solve that problem did you run into something that did not work as expected.  Is there a test case that fails, for example.  We can answer a question -- as long as the question isn't -- how do I solve this problem write all the code for me.  You have given us some code but no details on the problems you are having.  If I have to spend 3 hours to understand the solution to answer your question, I'm not going to.  If it takes me 10 mins then I'm happy to help.

Comment: You can find a lot of good resources in the help screens about how to ask a good question.  In this case I would suggest giving us the input data and the expected output data *and* what your current code is doing.   If you do this I expect someone will answer very quickly. (might even be me)

Answer (score 0):

Using the same extensions methods from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53231909/2557128), the same code should work, just for SS/SE instead of JS/JE:

```
var shiftErrEvents = itCompareDay
                        .Select((ev, rowNum) => new { ev.EventType, ev.EventDateTime, rowNum })
                        .Where(cd => cd.EventType == "SS" || cd.EventType == "SE")
                        .GroupByWhile((pd, cd) => pd.EventType == "SS" && cd.EventType == "SE" && pd.EventDateTime.Date == cd.EventDateTime.Date)
                        .Where(cdg => cdg.Count() != 2)
                        .SelectMany(cdg => cdg.Select(cd => new { cd.rowNum, ErrMsg = cd.EventType == "SE" ? "SE without preceding SS" : "SS without following SE" }));
```

Note: In both cases, a job or shift that crosses the midnight boundary (hence, is on different days) will be handled as two mismatched events.