# Iterate through linq query results by day to check conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a query that returns a list of events in a date range.

[image]

```
string EOOmessage = "";[enter image description here][2]
string eventText = "";
DateTime js = DateTime.Now;
DateTime je = DateTime.Now;
var itCompareDay = (from h in db.DailyGPSTables
                    where (h.EventDateTime >= startDate
                          && h.EventDateTime <= endDate)
                    select h).ToList();
```

I want to check the time for each event to make sure its in the proper sequence. For example JE(Job End) cannot be before JS(Job Start). I have tried many ways but this is my latest. It checks for a matching JE tag correctly but it doesn't account for which day it is in.

```
int rowNumber = -1;
foreach (DailyGPSTable e in itCompareDay)
{
    if (e.EventType == "JS")
    {
        js = e.EventDateTime.Value;
    }
    if (e.EventType == "JE")
    {
        je = e.EventDateTime.Value;
    }
    if (je < js)
    {
        EOOmessage = " On " + e.EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() + " Job end is before Job Start " + eventText;
        errorList.Add(EOOmessage);
        errorListRow.Add(rowNumber);
    }
    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;
}
```

Is there a way to check each day for out of sequence events and if found report them if not go to the next day?

Comment: Actually since the attribute is a DateTime, it should include the day in the comparison without you needing to check it manually.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code example you gave?

Comment: it checks the entire week not just the day.

Comment: so on the 1st it finds a je before a js but on the 3rd it finds another je abut doesn't realize there was another js on the 3rd. It's as if it uses the js on the 1st.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be more than one `JS`/`JE` pair on a day?

Comment: Yes, there can be many.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Can you post "desired output" so we can visualize what kind of result you're looking for?

Comment: I have added the screen shot in the link at the top. It shows the query finding a JS past a JE put it also finds another one. if I could limit results by day instead of week I think it will work.

Comment: In your screen shot, you have error row 2, 8 but that doesn't match the red rows? Also, since you have no job # to match times, I would suggest you have an unmatched JE and an unmatched JS on the first day, you don't know that they belong to the same job.

Comment: @NetMage start at 0

Comment: Sorry, miscounted :)

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension method that scans sequentially and groups while a test is true (or false) named `GroupByWhile` based on my extension method for scanning by pairs:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // TKey combineFn((TKey Key, T Value) PrevKeyItem, T curItem):
    // PrevKeyItem.Key = Previous Key
    // PrevKeyItem.Value = Previous Item
    // curItem = Current Item
    // returns new Key
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prevkv;
                    prevkv = (combineFn(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prevkv;
            }
        }
    }

    // bool testFn(T prevItem, T curItem)
    // returns groups by sequential matching bool
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> testFn) =>
        src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
           .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

You can select out the interesting event types (JS/JE) ordered by `EventDateTime` and then group by `JS` followed by `JE` and throw out matching pairs:

```
var itCompareDay = (from h in db.DailyGPSTables
                    where (h.EventDateTime >= startDate
                          && h.EventDateTime <= endDate)
                    orderby h.EventDateTime
                    select h).ToList();

var errEvents = itCompareDay
                    .Select((ev, rowNum) => new { ev.EventType, ev.EventDateTime, rowNum })
                    .Where(cd => cd.EventType == "JS" || cd.EventType == "JE")
                    .GroupByWhile((pd, cd) => pd.EventType == "JS" && cd.EventType == "JE" && pd.EventDateTime.Date == cd.EventDateTime.Date)
                    .Where(cdg => cdg.Count() != 2)
                    .SelectMany(cdg => cdg.Select(cd => new { cd.rowNum, ErrMsg = cd.EventType == "JE" ? "JE without preceding JS" : "JS without following JE" }));
```

Note that `rowNum` is 0 based but you could add 1 in the first `Select` if desired.

Comment: Wow, very impressive!

Comment: Thank You so much, I am having trouble implementing the extension class by simply copying and pasting your code into a new class

Comment: An extension must be implemented in a `static` class. I added the wrapper in the answer.

Comment: Still getting errors. I am adding a pic of the page

Comment: @NetMage I really appreciate your answer and would like to implement it. I have to leave the office now but would really appreciate the help on getting the GroupByWhile extensions set up on VS to operate..

Comment: No problem, perhaps you can provide more details on the errors, or research how to add extension methods to your project?

Comment: I have left the office but am working from home, do you have an email I can send screen shots to, This place didn't allow me to add another one. Do I have to do anything special with the code you sent? Intellisense is bugging out.

Comment: No, nothing special for the class - it is like any other class in your project. It must be only inside the project namespace (e.g. topmost class level). You can email me at wilsonpm at gamewood.net.